# Make web app work offline

Tags: android, web, offline

I've build a website and used https://gonative.io to create my Android app. This works fine as long as I keep my Website online. I want to make the app work offline.

In my .apk file all the data from my website is stored but is unused as far as I know.

Maybe someone here can help my.

Thank you for helping me.

Ronny

Comment: I yhink you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your app work in offline mode too, then you can use sqlite database. For this you can store all your data received from the website to the sqlite database and when you are offline you can always fetch your data stored in the database. More details on implementing sqlite database in android can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)